i have created the userController and also the email and the app passwords are connected well. But I couldn't get the otp through mail, why
I coudn't get the otp through the mail. I have created 2 step verification, then connected my email Id then the app passwords . signup form validation is proper.But I couldn't see the otp generated
I have provided a console.log to print the otp in the console, but it  doesn;t works. But the otp generation function is working but it doesn;t enter through the signup controller function . is there any suggestion for that .I have completed all the pre requisites for the otp sendfing alnd also for the logging of the otp..I have rechecked the app-password and also the email for the otp send. But that parts are clear and aslo the generate otp function outside the signup function is working. but i couldn't get the otp through the the provided email
